# my drop down menu is horizontal. i need it vertical

Tags: drop-down-menu

please help me i cant make my drop down list vertical. when I hover over a list it is horizontal.

my html code

```
<div id="header">
        <div>
            <a href="index.html" id="logo"><img src="logo.png" alt="LOGO" height="115" width="115px" /></a>

            <ul id="navigation">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="what.html">What We Offer</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Solutions</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="inbound.html">Inbound</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="outbound.html">Outbound</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

Comment: `enter code here` - where's the css? What styles are already applied?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your CSS, but did you apply `display: inline` to both the top-level AND sub-level menu items?  This will cause the problem you describe.

The top-level `li` items should be `display: inline,` but their children should be `display: block`.

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/tLqrrfy0/